# Can we create Test Suite Using WATIN?

Tags: .net, watin

I would like to know whether we can create Test Suites for WATIN. Im using WATIN to automate my Web Application. I was planning to create a set of Test Cases and save them in an Excel sheet and use WATIN to read data from them. But since its not posible using WATIN, I'm planning to create a Test Suite.

Comment: not a good idea to put your email there like that. You can use a rss reader with the feed of the question+answers (link at the bottom right)

Answer (score 2):

You need a testing framework like MbUnit (Gallio), xUnit.Net, NUnit, or MSTest to drive Watin and also to read data from an Excel-Sheet (this xls thing is easiest with xUnit.Net, because it has an extra attribute to utilize Excel data). With that in place, of course you can create everything you want/need/dream of.

Watin itself is not ment to be a real testing framework, but only kind of a 'driver' for browser-based tests.

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

As a personal choice, I would go with Thomas suggestion, WatiN is best used in conjunction with an UnitTest framework.

But there's a project, called Wax (http://wax.codeplex.com/), that can create test using data in an Excel file.

Never used it, nor I know much how it's work, but it may suite your taste and requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Can i create a web application to test my other applications, using Watin and any of the other frameworks mentioned by Thomas.

Because i was trying to do so using watiN and i was stuck in many problems.

I am a newbie. And using WatiN for the first time.

Thanks.
Majid